# Automatic building and installing Delphi components

Tags: delphi, components, vcl

So, my Delphi component is functional and working, aside few details yet to cover. What I would like is to create a setup (Inno setup) that would automatically install my component into user's Delphi/C++ Builder IDE. I presume I must use delphi command line compiler, but how?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you providing your components with source (I presume so?) and what version(s) of Delphi are you targeting?

Comment: That would be my second question: I need this component to work.. everywhere (Delphi and C++ Builder) regardless of their versions. I probably need to deliver source code as well? No problem, but is it possible not to deliver source and achive this installation?

Comment: Yes, you can provide precompiled DCU files, but you'd have to provide a different set for each Delphi version, and a set in both Release and Debug (for each respective Delphi version).

Comment: I thought so... It's to much complications. OK, so I'll deliver the source code. What's next step?

Comment: I was going to suggest having your InnoSetup wizard detect which versions of Delphi are installed, and use MSBuild against that version's DPROJ file (for the Package containing your component) to compile it. That'd spit out a .BPL file you can simply install into the IDE through the registry.
Since you're targeting versions earlier than 2006, that suggestion is now inadequate!

Comment: That would be great. It's no problem restricting it to version 2006.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately Delphi IDE does not support automated component installation at all. IMO, that is **very** big problem since component architecture is so important in Delphi.

You can build your package from command line (using MSBuild or DCC) but you cannot install it to IDE. To install your package you should write your own installer that builds you package, copies compiled files and updates Windows registry. Note there is no official documentation how to write such an installer, but you can take Jedi (JVCL) installer code as an example.

There are also 3rd party tools that automate component installation, for example '[lazy builder](http://www.lazyproject.info/)', that may be interesting to you.

Comment: Btw, Lazy Delphi Builder, uses code from JCL to read Delphi settings, compile and install components.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too hard, just messy. You need to compile a BPL for each Delphi version that you want to target and then your installer puts this BPL into a folder of your choosing (often users,public etc). This folder location is then written as a registry key under the relevant Delphi Installed Packages node. Lo when you run Delphi your components appear as if you had used the manual install packages option.